# Parsing a torrent info from multiple trackers and storing in a database

Tags: c#, parsing, bittorrent

When ever I see website like **BitSnoop** or **KickAssTorrents** one thing always comes to my mind is: *How do they get a torrent information from multiple trackers and store them perfectly in a database?.*

If you guys confused about what I'm talking about here's a screenshot from BitSnoop:

[image: bitnoop]
http://i54.tinypic.com/a2fbc3.png

In this torrent it has 3 different torrent trackers and all of them have different seeders/peers connected to them.

**So my question is like this**

- How do I parse a torrent with multiple trackers in .NET
- A best possible way to store this data in a database?

I tried to do this in ASP.NET MVC but every time I failed so some one please enlighten me with your knowledge ;)

Comment: Too broad.  What did you try and how did that fail would be a better question.

Comment: well somewhere in the database design i don't know how to store torrent status information in db

Comment: This sounds completely unrelated to ASP.NET MVC. Perhaps you would fail less if you started in the right place. :)

Comment: @bzlm: Agreed.  What does this have to do with MVC-anything?

Comment: @bzlm @yodaj007 I agree that it does not have to do anything with ASP.NET MVC i just tried creating an app similar to BitSnoop or KickAssTorrent & i got stuck at this point that's it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The folks are right; your question is extremely vague and ambigious (you don't even mention a language, just '.NET'!), and yet you appear to want an actual solution, which would require a language to be specified, so I added the C# tag.

Well anyway, let's start with parsing the torrrent...

[Torrent files](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torrent_file) are [bencoded](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bencode), so you should probably search for a wrapper class that allows simple encoding/decoding.

Just download the file into a string and pass into the class.

As the Wikipedia page states, multiple trackers are kept inside the `announce-list` key. All you'll need to do is parse this and you've got your multiple trackers.

As for the best way to store these in the database, I'll leave to someone with more knowledge of torrents, but it looks like a one-to-many-to-one relationship should be utilised.

- Table 1 would contain information on the actual torrent.
- Table 2 would contain the tracker urls.
- Table 3 would be a lookup between table 1 and table 2.

I hope this helps. And I also hope you put more effort in before turning to the Internets for help! Nerd my arse! ;)

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Dan you're right I should have put more effort on it before running to the Internets. But it will do.